# Python script with Multithreading was killed due to out of memory

Tags: python-3.x

I have used threading module to process the data faster. The python program is killed as the memory usage keeps on increasing as the time goes. Here is the simple example to reproduce the issue. What is wrong with this code? Where the memory leakage is happening. Thanks for your help.

```
import threading

import time

def f1():return

def f2():

    for i in (1,300):
        t = threading.Thread(target=f1)
        t.start()
    return


def main():

    while True:
        for i in range(1,200):

            t = threading.Thread(target=f2)
            t.start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got threads creating threads???  and 200 threads each creating 300 threads, for a total of 60,000 threads?

I think any machine will likely run out of memory trying to do this.

Your code has no memory leak, and there is nothing 'wrong' with it, except what you are trying to do is just, well, completely wrong.

So perhaps you should explain a bit of background about what you're trying to achieve and why.

Comment: Thank you Richard. In my real use case I need to create 5 threads each gets a list of 30 elements and creates a thread for processing(storing into a file) each element for parallel processing. Thus my program creates 150 threads for each iteration. My python program consumes all memory and it gets killed though each thread returns instantly. When each thread returns instantly, why there is out of memory issue?

Comment: Threads don't come for free, and without seeing your code I'd guess 150 threads is using all your memory up.  It sounds like you need to rethink the algorithm you're using.  For one, if you're CPU bound you should be using multiprocessing, not threading (see any of a million articles on python concurrency).  Separately, if you're IO bound you would probably be better of architecting it using asynio (or more simply, just coroutines or generators) to do your processing.  It sounds like you're trying to do a non-trivial task/approach - you need to do some background research first.

Comment: 150 theads are not using all memory. The memory is getting increased as the time goes(it was killed after 4 hours). But somehow t.join() has resolved my out of memory issue.